# Format tilelayer.wms URL properties such that I add an overlay iteratively to my base map in Leaflet

Tags: geoserver, javascript, wms, leaflet, getfeatureinfo

My base map was created using hard-coded template variables. I am using the leaflet `tilelayer.wms` constructor and including the URL like so:

```
url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sf/wmsservice=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=sf:archsites&styles=&bbox=589851.4376666048,4914490.882968263,608346.4603107043,4926501.8980334345&width=512&height=332&srs=EPSG:26713"
```

So I'm grabbing a WMS layer from GeoServer and I'm trying to make it display in my Leaflet base map, but I don't think I have to actually go about creating a feature group. I think the URL could possibly be simply:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sf/wmsservice=WMS
```

but then that would mean I need to structure the layer property which I am also unsure how to do so correctly. I think essentially I want to satisfy the `GetCapabilities`, `GetMap`, and `GetFeatureInfo` requests using Leaflet's API. And I think this is possible to do by utilizing only the layer group methods and the tilelayer methods. In addition I don't want to have to utilize `onclick` to retrieve the `GetFeatureInfo` because essentially I am adding in data programmatically.

I've seen examples utilizing the `onClick` eventlistener to do this, but I'd like it to be a toggle under the layer controls for visibility as it still is an overlay. So essentially I'd like to have a controls based listener as opposed to `onclick`.

Comment: The URL is simply: `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sf/wms?`